# Discriminant of $\sum_{k=0}^n x^k$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, discriminant

Please help me find discriminant of $\sum_{k=0}^n x^k$. I guess we should find

Res($\sum_{k=0}^n x^k, \sum_{k=1}^n kx^{k-1}$)

by counting an appropriate Sylvester's determinant, but I can't find a simple way to solve it.

This is a task of increased difficulty given on an algebra seminar at HSE Math faculty.

Comment: Except for sign, it's given by https://oeis.org/A000272. The sequence of signs seems to be periodic: $+ + - - \cdots$

Comment: Thank you so much! Maybe you know where I can get the proof?

Comment: My instinct is to use $(x-1)\sum_{k=0}^n x^k = x^{n+1}-1$ together with the formula $\mathop{\rm disc}(fg) = \mathop{\rm disc}(f)\mathop{\rm disc}(g)\mathop{\rm Res}(f,g)^2$.

Comment: Could those who are voting to close this question give a reason for doing so so the author can improve the question? What particular context is missing?

Comment: This was not a bad question in my opinion, but it seems others disagree. Parhaps you could salvage it by providing a specific attempt at a proof, even if it is fruitless.

Answer (score 5):

Let $f:=\sum_{k=0}^nX^k$ and note that $(X-1)f=X^{n+1}-1$. Then
$$\Delta(X^{n+1}-1)=\Delta(f)\Delta(X-1)\operatorname{Res}(f,X-1)^2.$$
Of course $\Delta(X-1)=1$ and
$$\operatorname{Res}(f,X-1)=\operatorname{Res}(f(1),X-1)=\operatorname{Res}(n+1,X-1)=n+1.$$
We can compute $\Delta(X^{n+1}-1)=\operatorname{Res}(X^{n+1}-1,(n+1)X^n)$ as in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/890106/discriminant-of-xn-1?noredirect=1) to find that
$$\Delta(X^{n+1}-1)=(n+1)^{n+1}(-1)^{(n+1)(n+2)/2+1}.$$
It follows that
$$\Delta(f)=(n+1)^{n-1}(-1)^{(n+1)(n+2)/2+1}=(-1)^{(n^2-n)/2}(n+1)^{n-1}.$$

---

Alternatively, you can compute the discriminant directly. From $(X-1)f=X^{n+1}-1$ we see that the roots of $f$ are precisely $\zeta^k$ for $k=1,\ldots,n$ where $\zeta$ is a primitive $n+1$-th root of unity. Then
$$\Delta(f):=\prod_{i<j}(\zeta^i-\zeta^j)^2=(-1)^{n(n+1)/2}\prod_{i\neq j}(\zeta^i-\zeta^j).$$
With the observation that
$$\prod_{j=1}^n(1-\zeta^j)=f(1)=n+1,$$
it readily follows, by reindexing the products, that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\prod_{i\neq j}(\zeta^i-\zeta^j)
&=&\prod_{i=1}^n\prod_{\substack{j=1\\ i+j\neq n+1}}^n(\zeta^i-\zeta^{i+j})\\
&=&\prod_{i=1}^n\left((\zeta^i-1)^{-1}\prod_{j=1}^n(\zeta^i-\zeta^{i+j})\right)\\
&=&\prod_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{\zeta^{ni}}{\zeta^i-1}\prod_{j=1}^n(1-\zeta^j)\right)\\
&=&\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{(n+1)\zeta^{ni}}{\zeta^i-1}\\
&=&(n+1)^n\zeta^{n^2(n+1)/2}\frac{1}{\prod_{i=1}^n(1-\zeta^i)}\\
&=&(n+1)^{n-1}\zeta^{n^2(n+1)/2}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now note that $\zeta^{n^2(n+1)/2}=1$ if $n$ is even, and otherwise it equals $-1$. So $\zeta^{n^2(n+1)/2}=(-1)^n$ and hence
$$\Delta(f)=(-1)^{n(n-3)/2}(n+1)^{n-1}.$$